# How to get element in nativescript using vue?

Tags: vue.js, nativescript

I want to get Image element with `id='item'` on created.

I can't seem to find anything on google. Most of the tutorial on the internet is using Typescript and always start with `page=args.object`

```
export function pageLoaded(args) {
    page = args.object;
    item = page.getViewById("item");
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use refrences for this.

Sample xml:

```
<StackLayout ~body class="body" row="1">
```

or:

```
<StackLayout ref="body" class="body" row="1">
```

Sample code:

```
mounted() {
  let body = this.$refs.body;
}
```

Comment: Also you can access the nativeview by accessing it's property:

let nativeLayout = this.$refs.body.nativeView;

Comment: May I ask, where do you found this? Is it on the official document or vue document?

Comment: @GTHell I found this at: https://github.com/nativescript-vue/nativescript-vue/issues/49 I always try to find a solution for my questions via the nativescript documentation, the vue documentation, the nativescript-vue documentation, the nativescript repository and the nativescript-vue repository. If I can't find anything there I ask the slack community or on Stackoverflow.

Answer (score 6):

As mentioned in the comments of the other answers:

```
<StackLayout ref="body" class="body" row="1">

mounted() {
  let body = this.$refs.body;
}
```

> Also you can access the `nativeView` by accessing it's property: let
>   `nativeLayout = this.$refs.body.nativeView`;

In NativeScript-Vue the `nativeView` of a `ViewComponent` is the wrapper element of the actual native platform (iOS/Android) element/view.

For example the `nativeView` of the `ref="body"` is the `StackLayout` of the [tns-core-modules](https://github.com/NativeScript/NativeScript/blob/3efc06ed986b114e7ff52764e3cb78c07ad7c8c9/tns-core-modules/ui/layouts/stack-layout/stack-layout.ios.ts#L6) and it has a `nativeViewProtected` property which is the actual native framework element (on iOS [UIView](https://github.com/NativeScript/NativeScript/blob/3efc06ed986b114e7ff52764e3cb78c07ad7c8c9/tns-core-modules/ui/layouts/layout-base.ios.ts#L8) and [android.view.View](https://github.com/NativeScript/NativeScript/blob/3efc06ed986b114e7ff52764e3cb78c07ad7c8c9/tns-core-modules/ui/core/view/view.android.ts#L259) on Android)